# Using a custom protocol with XMLHttpRequest in a Firefox add-on

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk, protocol-handler

I've created an addon that defines a custom protocol; blabla:

for now `blabla:***` just redirects to google.com - this works fine.

However, I want to execute a XMLHttpRequest to get the real URL it should redirect to. But from the moment I add this 1 line (nothing else yet), the addon stops functioning:

```js
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
```

Are there special rules for custom protocol addons that I'm not aware of? (such as no xmlhttprequests)? Is there no way around this?

```js
var wheretogo = WhereToGo(resource);
var uri = ioservice.newURI(wheretogo, null, null);
var channel = ioservice.newChannelFromURI(uri, null).QueryInterface(Ci.nsIHttpChannel);


function  WhereToGo(fres) {       
  //  var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

  return 'http://google.com';
}
```

EDIT:

I'm now using this code :

```js
    var request = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/xmlextras/xmlhttprequest;1"] .createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsIXMLHttpRequest);
    request.open("GET", "http://localhost:5000/?request=" + fres, false); //synchronous
    request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    request.send(null);
```

But getting this error:

```js
[Exception... "Failure"  nsresult: "0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE)"  location: "JS frame :: file:///Users/wesley/Desktop/ProtocolFx/components/Protocol.js :: WhereToGo :: line 51"  data: no]
```

Any idea why this doesn't work? (Is it because of the port number?) I thought XMLHttpRequest was allowed to be cross domain in firefox addons?

When I change it to fetch http://google.com/ instead of localhost, I get a response.status of 0 and a response.responseText of ''

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `XMLHttpRequest` constructor is only defined in the context of DOM windows. If your code is running in a different context (like an SDK module which is essentially a sandbox) this constructor will not be defined and you have to create an instance via XPCOM:

```js
var {Cc, Ci} = require("chrome");
var request = Cc["@mozilla.org/xmlextras/xmlhttprequest;1"]
                .createInstance(Ci.nsIXMLHttpRequest);
```

For reference: [chrome authority](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/dev-guide/tutorials/chrome.html), [Using XMLHttpRequest from JavaScript modules / XPCOM components](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest#Using_XMLHttpRequest_from_JavaScript_modules_.2F_XPCOM_components).

Note that the usual recommendation for SDK-based extensions is using the [`request` module](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/modules/sdk/request.html) which has the advantage of automatically canceling your request if the extension is disabled/uninstalled. There is also the low-level [`net/xhr` module](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/modules/sdk/net/xhr.html) providing an interface that is similar to the native `XMLHttpRequest` and that will also cancel requests automatically if needed. However, from all I know neither of the two will give access to the `XMLHttpRequest.channel` property that is required to find the "real" URL of the request.

Comment: Palant - Thank you for your help. I'm very new to firefox addon development. Your code has helped, but I'm not out of the woods yet. It seems my xmlhttprequest is not executing correctly. See my updated question. I'm hoping you have some further ideas of what could be the cause?

Comment: @Wesley: This is an exception in your protocol handler which is a very different issue from the one you were asking about originally. It is probably better to create a new question and to provide some details about how you implemented your protocol. `XMLHttpRequest` seems to be working correctly.